# How to use automatic provisioning for iOS builds in Azure Pipeline

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use the automatic provisioning for iOS builds.  On my Mac it works correctly, but when I tried to do it on Azure pipeline I get the following error

```
error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'XXX' from project 'XXXX')
error: No profiles for 'com.devhaus.ljdev' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.XXXX'. (in target 'XXXX' from project 'XXXX')
```

In my yaml I only have the `InstallAppleCertificate` task which runs successfully

```yaml
          - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
            inputs:
              certSecureFile: $(p12File)
              certPwd: $(p12Password)

          - script: |
              npx run ionic build 
            displayName: "build"

          - script: |
              npx ionic cordova platform add ios@6
            displayName: "build for Apple"

# Didn't just do npx ionic cordova build ios here as there 
# is a bug that will cause the build to hang.

          - script: |
              npx cordova build ios --device
            displayName: "build for IOS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7302) that automatic signing only works for development builds. you cannot use auto signing in a DevOps pipeline for distribution(ad hoc, app store, etc).

However, you can always manually sign your ios by specifying the **codeSignIdentity** and **provisioningProfile** parameters to build command. For below example command. See cordova document [Signing an App](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/#signing-an-app)

```
 npx cordova build ios --device --codeSignIdentity="$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" --provisioningProfile="$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"
```

When you use  **Install Apple Certificate** and  **Install Apple Provisioning Profile** tasks to download the certificate and provisioning profile in azure devops pipeline. Variables `$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)` and `$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)` are automatically set by these tasks, which allows you to refer to the Signing identity and Provisioning profile UUID directly.  See Microsoft document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=azure-devops&tabs=apple-install-during-build#sign-your-apple-ios-macos-tvos-or-watchos-app).

> In the Signing identity field, enter $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY). This variable is automatically set by the Install Apple Certificate task for the certificate you selected.

> In the Provisioning profile UUID field, enter $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID). This variable is automatically set by the Install Apple Provisioning Profile task for the provisioning profile you selected.